# How to change the blue point style in Interaction modify

Tags: openlayers

I use ol/interaction/Draw and ol/interaction/Modify to draw circles and can change. But I don't know how to show the center point and the point on the circle instead of having to hover over it and replace the blue dot with the icon.
It looks like this picture

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/51256090/58744368-e92e3f00-846b-11e9-9969-5e3b06e75429.png

Answer (score 1):

You can show the center of a circle by styling it with a style function which adds a style for the center geometry.  You can set new styles or style functions for modify and draw interactions.  In this demo the red center of the circle changes to the green modify style when the pointer approaches it and can be seen through the hollow style of the draw when it's not drawing

```js
  var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  });

  var vectorStyle = new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#ffcc33',
        width: 2
      }),
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 7,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: '#ffcc33'
        })
      })
  });

  var centerStyle = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 7,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'red'
        })
      })
  });

  var modifyStyle = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 7,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'green'
        })
      })
  });

  var drawStyle = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 7,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          width: 1,
          color: 'black'
        })
      })
  });

  var source = new ol.source.Vector();
  var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source,
    style: function(feature){
      var styles = [vectorStyle];
      if (feature.getGeometry().getType() == 'Circle') {
        centerStyle.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(feature.getGeometry().getCenter()));
        styles.push(centerStyle);
      }
      return styles;
    }
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster, vector],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [-11000000, 4600000],
      zoom: 4
    })
  });

  var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({source: source, style: modifyStyle});
  map.addInteraction(modify);

  var draw, snap; // global so we can remove them later
  var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');

  var defaultEditStyle = new ol.interaction.Select().getOverlay().getStyleFunction();

  function addInteractions() {
    var drawing = false;
    draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
      source: source,
      type: typeSelect.value,
      style: function(feature) {
        if (drawing) {
          return defaultEditStyle(feature);
        } else {
          return drawStyle;
        }
      }
    });
    draw.on('drawstart', function(){ drawing = true; });
    draw.on('drawend', function(){ drawing = false; });
    map.addInteraction(draw);
    snap = new ol.interaction.Snap({source: source});
    map.addInteraction(snap);

  }

  /**
   * Handle change event.
   */
  typeSelect.onchange = function() {
    map.removeInteraction(draw);
    map.removeInteraction(snap);
    addInteractions();
  };

  addInteractions();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<form class="form-inline">
  <label>Geometry type &nbsp;</label>
  <select id="type">
    <option value="Point">Point</option>
    <option value="LineString">LineString</option>
    <option value="Polygon">Polygon</option>
    <option value="Circle" selected>Circle</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. This is almost what I need. I want to ask further if I want to remove the mouseover feature from the center and change it to a green point but instead only have a red anchor point but still pull and move the circle by the anchor point.

Comment: `modifyStyle` could be the same as `centerStyle`, although it would be difficult to know if the pointer was close enough to drag the center, or not close enough when it would drag the map.